# Can http context get lost with async await?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, async-await

from time to time our application crashs because of this error: https://serverfault.com/questions/675649/accessviolationexception-iis, I dont want to dicuss this error itself but have some questions about a possible reason:

I had look to the code in system.web with ILSpy and I have got the impression that the http runtime looses the context (and an unmanaged pointer) and therefore crashs. I have no details about the exception so I checked all code and everything is very straight forwared besides one api call.

It more or less looks like this (pseudo code):

```
private async Task SearchAsync()
{
   Func<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext, Task> searching = 
       async (stream, content, transportContext) =>
   {
      StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

      Action<Data> write = new Action<Data>()
      {   
          writer.WriteData(data);
          writer.WriteLine();
          writer.Flush();
      };

      List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

      foreach (IService service in services)
      {
         tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => service.CallAsync(write));
      };

      await Task.WhenAny(
         Task.Delay(10000),
         Task.WhenAll(tasks));
   };

   response.Content = new PushStreamContent(searching, "text/event-stream");
}
```

It looks a little bit strange but the reason is the following:

- We need to trigger some services, half of them dont have any async client library yet. We also do some processing before and after the service call, like calling db (not async, thank you mongo driver) and making cpu-intensive calculations.
- Each service can take a very long time (e.g. 1min) to answer. Therefore we try to push the content to the response stream as soon as it is available.
- We dont want to user to wait so long, so we cancel the request for the user but continue the search, so the data is available the next time.

So the question is: Can the http context get lost in some way in this code? By lost in mean the following: In the linked question you see that a native methode fails inside system.web. Probably because the IntPtr (coming from the http context) passed to this method is not valid anymore

Are there any potential issues I dont see? How to deal with parallel tasks in IIS correctly?

---

**Edit:** Why is service.CallAsync Async?

The code simplifies the real situation. In my code the service is a wrapper around a real service. Each service has multiple steps, a lot of classes and multiple levels of mediators, but the structure is like this:

```
GetFromDatabase(); // Not async yet, because of mongo driver.
await CallServiceAsync(); // Sometimes async, sometimes not, depending on service.
PrepareResults(); // Not async, but cpu intensive.
```

So in my point of view, it makes sense, to parallelize it to reduce response time.

Comment: Why is the method `async` at all? You just create a delegate and pass it on.

Comment: Also, `StreamWriter` isn't thread-safe and you're using it from multiple threads.

Comment: @i3arnon - most likely real code have lock on `writer` action to just deal with the fact `StreamWriter` (and likely underlying custom stream) is not thread safe.

Comment: Very hard to see what you mean "lost" - clearly calls to `service.Call` will have no HttpContext to start with, so it is not where failure can happen (even when the calls run past end of request), but there is no other places in code you've shown that have anything interesting going on about HttpContext.

Comment: @i3arnon: Yes, there is a lock on streamwriter, I also added the reason to my post, why the method is async and edited the code a little bit (the services can be async).

Comment: @Alexei: I added some information. It a sounds a little bit obscure, I know (for me as well).

Comment: @SebastianStehle I still see no reason for `SearchAsync` to be async. Only `searching` needs to be. Also, mongo's new driver supports async.

Answer (score 7):

HttpContext is stored on the SynchronizationContext. By offloading to a ThreadPool thread with Task.Run you are not using the SC and so you don't have access to the HttpContext.

If `CallAsync` is an async method you don't really need to use Task.Run here and you can just store the returned task instead:

```
 tasks.Add(service.CallAsync(write);
```

If you still need Task.Run you can pass the HttpContext manually:

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => 
{
    HttpContext.Current = context;
    service.CallAsync(write)
});
```

Comment: Yes, i know the "problem" with the synchronizationcontext and dont access HttpContext inside. Probably the question is a little bit too obscure for SO. I am just hunting this annoying bug and try to eliminate all possible issues.

Comment: @SebastianStehle What do you mean? If you know there isn't an http context. What is your question?

Comment: One example could be the following potential issue: lets say the user cancels the http request and the iis stops the request, so the http context is gone. What happens with the tasks running the searches? They are still running and try to write the results to the stream. What happens now? I never got any exception here, but it might be an issue. For example the stream is still valid and after the search is done, the PushStreamContent tries to finish the request (which fails with the accessviolationexception).

Comment: @SebastianStehle I don't think the IIS can stop a request before it completes. Anyways, that's still not a question.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Will close the question, because it is not specific enough.